# Error Installing Python Libraries through Nexus Repo Manager

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am currently trying to install two libraries.

Running: `C:\Users\J39304\Desktop>python -m pip install pyinstaller` yields me the following error:

```
>     C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python -m pip install pyinstaller
>     Looking in indexes: https://repo-manager-location-proprietarysimple
>     Collecting pyinstaller
>     
>     
>       Using cached https://repo-manager-location-proprietarypackages/03/32/hash/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz
>     
>     
>       Installing build dependencies ... error
>       ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Python35-32\python.exe' 'C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed
> --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\jerry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a6x0i3h0\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://repo-manager-location-proprietarysimple -- setuptools wheel:
>       
>     
>     ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
>           "__main__", mod_spec)
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>           exec(code, run_globals)
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
>           from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40,
> in <module>
>           from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py",
> line 8, in <module>
>           from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py",
> line 12, in <module>
>           from pip._internal.commands import (
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py",
> line 6, in <module>
>           from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py",
> line 6, in <module>
>           from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py",
> line 25, in <module>
>           from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 41, in
> <module>
>           from pip._internal.wheel import Wheel
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 7, in
> <module>
>           import compileall
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
>           from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\__init__.py",
> line 8, in <module>
>           from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
>         File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line
> 414
>           raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
>                               ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>       ----------------------------------------
>     ERROR: 
>     Command "'C:\Python35-32\python.exe' 
>     'C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\jerry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a6x0i3h0\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://repo-manager-location-proprietarysimple -- setuptools wheel"
> failed with error code 1 in None
```

I also noticed that running a similar command, `C:\Users\J39304\Desktop>python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe`, results in the exact same error.

However, when I ran `C:\Users\J39304\Desktop>python -m pip install keras` it installed just fine.

I have already made sure that I am using the latest version of `pip` by running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I have not found any resources for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raise X, Y` is Python2-only syntax. Somehow you've managed to install a Python2-only library to Python3 `site-packages`. You need to cleanup  `site-packages` and install newer versions of libraries.

Comment: I assume `site-packages` is something in the Nexus Repo Manager, so I should bring that up with that sys admin team, then?

Comment: I see the problem in `C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py` so start with removing `C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\concurrent\`.